# how to query instances from GCP project directly

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am working on a tool to pull all the instances running under several projects in multiple GCP regions/zones. I know I can pull the instances from /projects/zones//instances by querying each zone for each project. but i want to be able to pull instances directly from projects . is there a way i can do this using gcp apis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/aggregated/instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList)